# Unconfirmed Transaction using Blockchain.info wallet

Tags: wallet, unconfirmed-transactions

I sent 0.08 BTC yesterday using the blockchain.info wallet on the iPhone.

It's been 24 hours and my money is still unsent; I really don't know what to do. It still says unconfirmed. Why is this? What can I do?

[Transaction in question.](https://blockchain.info/tx/7e3b70a23c46eeed599558e049948319a3524edd3355611a80b92b9867f12b88)

Answer (score 1):

The previous transaction that you are using to spend the coin is also unconfirmed. See below. Looks like this is a problem with the blockchain wallet that you want to email their tech support about. It doesn't even seem to be broadcasting the transactions anymore.

https://blockchain.info/tx/2bf18c5ba2fe56f3d9ada4880181518e905f275bfc9826fdbebd07dca34f2ef2

If you want to fix the problem yourself, you could manually broadcast the transactions out by first getting the transaction hex :

https://blockchain.info/tx/2bf18c5ba2fe56f3d9ada4880181518e905f275bfc9826fdbebd07dca34f2ef2?format=hex

And using:

https://blockchain.info/pushtx

Comment: I tried that and it said "transaction already exists".